# cElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have a large XML file (details of 2 million object) having contents similar to as shown below. Size of file is 657MB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8?>
<root>
    <item>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <landinglink>www.google.com</landinglink>
        <descrip>some text</descrip>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <landinglink>www.facebook.com</landinglink>
        <descrip>some text</descrip>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rank>1</rank>
        <landinglink>www.xyz.com</landinglink>
        <descrip>some text</descrip>
    </item>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
</root>
```

I am trying to print all the 'landinglink'. The code which I am using is as shown below.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
for event, elem in ET.iterparse("filename.xml"):
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'item':
        print elem.find('landinglink').text
```

but while executing the code it gives me following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse("filename.xml"):
  File "<string>", line 91, in next
cElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1338, column 298
```

This error keeps on repeating at different location. How to avoid this type of error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is on that line, at that position?

Comment: some textual descriptions but it contains xA0 kind of some error

Comment: If the value is `\xA0`, then your file isn't properly encoded as utf-8.

Comment: how to solve this issue

Comment: The first thing I would try is changing the XML declaration to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="latin=1" ?>` and seeing what happens.

Comment: after changing I get error as cElementTree.ParseError: XML declaration not well-formed

Comment: My mistake, instead of `latin-1`, use `iso-8859-1`

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(posting as an answer for later readers)

If the bad token value is `\xA0`, then the file isn't properly encoded as utf-8.
If the file only has 8-bit characters, you need to change the XML declaration to something else, probably `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>`.